# Using Play2(Scala) validation without Forms

Tags: scala, validation, playframework-2.2

I want to use play2 validation framework but without using forms and bindings,
i have a single string that i want to check if it's an email or not without re-implementing the validation functionality

e.g

```
Validation.emailAddress("")
```

I looked/tried into this class [Validation.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/validation/Validation.scala) but didn't figure out how to use it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tag you've stated that you're using Playframework 2.2. This method does not exist in [Play 2.2 source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/validation/Validation.scala).

If there was one, you could call it just like this

```
import play.api.data.validation._
val validationResult = Constraints.emailAddress("test@whatever.com")
```

You can test it by copying the method from the sources you linked to or by using Play 2.3.

Comment: You forget to add "Constraints"
val validationResult = Constraints.emailAddress("test@whatever.com")